# Default height for the html input element in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, input, height, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a problem with the input height in IE10, basically I have this input:

its height is 20px on Chrome, IE9 and Firefox, but not on IE10 where it is 18px.

This fact is affecting the way the page is displayed because the input and the dropdown icon on the right are not alligned

[image: problem with IE10 input element]

Do you have any idea about that? Is it possible that IE10 renders the input elements in a different way?

Comment: is it possible that the same input field has different size in IE10?

Comment: is it possible that IE10 doesn't take into account the 2px of the top and bottom border of the input element?

Because I see there is a difference of 2 px between Chrome and IE10

Comment: increase your chances to get an answer by posting a live demo of your problem on jsbin.com